# Superposition Principle and Forces

Tags: forces, superposition, coulombs-law

Why does Griffiths write in his book -

"For not only does the force on test charge $Q$ depend on the separation distance $r$ between the charges, it also depends on both their velocities and on the acceleration of source charge $q$"?

Does he mean Lorentz force here?

---

Reference: D. J. Griffiths, *Introduction to Electrodynamics Ed. 4*, Pages 59-60

Comment: Lorentz force does not depend explicitly on acceleration. Could you be more precise about the quotation from Griffiths? which book and chapter?

Comment: Introduction to Electrodynamics by David J Griffiths, 4th edition, Chapter 2, last two lines of  Page 59 and first line of page 60.

Comment: Maybe it is better to edit your question accordingly. Then we could delete our comments.

Comment: I think that if one tries to write the functional form of  electromagnetic  forces between charges, only  in terms of kinematic properties of the sources, then he/she is forced to include accelerations (the full motion actually) of the sources... indeed it is a desperate task. Probably the textbook is motivating the introduction of the notion of electromagnetic field.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, he means the Lorentz force.

Well, this of two charges which are at distance, r , from each other and are at rest. The Force is only proportional to r.

Now, if one is at rest and the other one is moving at constant velocity v. The Force is proportional to r and there is also the magnetic field which is created by the moving particle. The strength of the force of the magnetic field is proportional to v. So total force is proportional to r and v.
Note that as the particle moves and gets closer or farther away the strength of the magnetic field changes.

In the last case consider a charge at rest and another charge rotating around it such that the strength not the magnetic field which is created by the rotation particle is constant where the other particle is at rest.